# DDPG - Actor Critic Network does not converge with continous Actionspace

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, convergence

I'm currently a bit confused. I implemented an Actor-Critic Network and depending on the setup ist either begins to converge a little but produces values far from right. Or it produces the nearly the same loss values over and over again but right from the start produces values which are kind of correct.
I really have no clue how that is possible.
This is my current Model which produces values but does not converge:

```
def create_actor_model(self):
    state_input = Input(shape=self.observation_space_shape)
    h1 = Dense(18, activation='linear')(state_input)
    h1l = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01)(h1)
    h3 = Dense(18, activation='tanh')(h1l)
    h3n = BatchNormalization()(h3)
    output = Dense(self.action_space_shape[0], activation='tanh')(h3n)
    model = Model(input=state_input, output=output)
    adam = Adam(lr=self.action_space_shape)
    model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=adam)
    return state_input, model

def create_critic_model(self):
    state_input = Input(shape=self.observation_space_shape)
    state_h1 = Dense(18, activation='relu')(state_input)
    state_h2 = Dense(36)(state_h1)

    action_input = Input(shape=self.action_space_shape)
    action_h1 = Dense(36)(action_input)

    merged = Add()([state_h2, action_h1])
    l_h1 = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01)(merged)
    merged_h1 = Dense(18, activation='tanh')(l_h1)
    h1n = BatchNormalization()(merged_h1)
    output = Dense(1, activation='tanh')(h1n)
    model = Model(input=[state_input, action_input], output=output)

    adam = Adam(lr=self.action_space_shape)
    model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=adam, metrics=['mae', 'mse', 'msle'])
    return state_input, action_input, model


 def _train_actor_batch(self, batch_size, s_batch, a_batch, r_batch, s2_batch):
    predicted_action = self.actor_model.predict_on_batch(s_batch)
    grads = self.sess.run(self.critic_grads, feed_dict={
        self.critic_state_input: s_batch,
        self.critic_action_input: predicted_action
    })

    self.sess.run(self.optimize, feed_dict={
        self.actor_state_input: s_batch,
        self.actor_critic_grad: grads[0]
    })

def _train_critic_batch(self, batch_size, s_batch, a_batch, r_batch, s2_batch):
    target_action = self.target_actor_model.predict_on_batch(s2_batch)
    future_reward = self.target_critic_model.predict_on_batch([s2_batch, target_action])

    rewards = []
    for k in range(batch_size):
        this_future_reward = future_reward[k] if batch_size > 1 else future_reward
        rewards.append(r_batch[k] + self.gamma * this_future_reward)

    return self.critic_model.train_on_batch([s_batch, a_batch], np.reshape(rewards, batch_size))

def replay(self, batch_size):
    memory_length = len(self.memory)
    if memory_length < batch_size:
        samples = random.sample(self.memory, memory_length)
    else:
        samples = random.sample(self.memory, batch_size)

    s_batch = np.array([cur_state[0] for cur_state, _, _, _ in samples])
    a_batch = np.array([float(action[0]) for _, action, _, _ in samples])
    r_batch = np.array([reward[0] for _, _, reward, _ in samples])
    s2_batch = np.array([new_state[0] for _, _, _, new_state in samples])

    critic_loss = self._train_critic_batch(len(s_batch), s_batch, a_batch, r_batch, s2_batch)
    self._train_actor_batch(len(s_batch), s_batch, a_batch, r_batch, s2_batch)

    self.update_target()
    return critic_loss

def _update_actor_target(self):
    actor_model_weights = self.actor_model.get_weights()
    actor_target_weights = self.target_actor_model.get_weights()

    for i in range(len(actor_target_weights)):
        actor_target_weights[i] = actor_model_weights[i] * self.tau + actor_target_weights[i] * (1 - self.tau)
    self.target_actor_model.set_weights(actor_target_weights)

def _update_critic_target(self):
    critic_model_weights = self.critic_model.get_weights()
    critic_target_weights = self.target_critic_model.get_weights()

    for i in range(len(critic_target_weights)):
        critic_target_weights[i] = critic_model_weights[i] * self.tau + critic_target_weights[i] * (1 - self.tau)
    self.target_critic_model.set_weights(critic_target_weights)

def update_target(self):
    self._update_actor_target()
    self._update_critic_target()



def __init__(self):
    self.memory = deque(maxlen=2000)
    self.actor_state_input, self.actor_model = self.create_actor_model()
    _, self.target_actor_model = self.create_actor_model()

    self.actor_critic_grad = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.action_space_shape[0]])

    actor_model_weights = self.actor_model.trainable_weights
    self.actor_grads = tf.gradients(self.actor_model.output,
                                    actor_model_weights, -self.actor_critic_grad)
    grads = zip(self.actor_grads, actor_model_weights)
    self.optimize = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.learning_rate).apply_gradients(grads)

    self.critic_state_input, self.critic_action_input, \
    self.critic_model = self.create_critic_model()
    _, _, self.target_critic_model = self.create_critic_model()

    self.critic_grads = tf.gradients(self.critic_model.output,
                                     self.critic_action_input)

    self.sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
```

And then i am training with the following method which is called for each epoch (at the end, the memory which is getting cleared is the experience-replay memory):

```
def train(self, states, epoch, env, is_new_epoch):
    train_size = int(len(states) * 0.70)

    train = dict(list(states.items())[0:train_size])
    test = dict(list(states.items())[train_size:len(states)])
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.simplefilter("ignore")

        working_states = copy(train)

        critic_eval = list()
        rewards = dict()
        for last_day, (last_state_vec, _, last_action) in working_states.items():
            this_day = last_day + timedelta(days=1)
            if this_day in working_states:
                (new_state_vec, _, _) = working_states.get(this_day)
                rewards[last_day] = env.get_reward_by_states(last_state_vec, new_state_vec)

        amt = len(working_states)
        i = 0
        for last_day, (last_state_vec, _, last_action) in working_states.items():
            i+= 1
            this_day = last_day + timedelta(days=1)
            if this_day in working_states:
                (new_state_vec, _, _) = working_states.get(this_day)
                reward = np.reshape(rewards[last_day], [1, ])
                self.remember(last_state_vec, [last_action], reward, new_state_vec)
                new_eval = self.replay(env.batch_size)
                critic_eval.append(new_eval)
         self.memory.clear()
```

These are the loss values i got over 15 epochs:
[image: Actor Critic loss values over 15 epochs]

One Sample as it comes from the memory:

```
state
  [8 79 48246 53607 29 34 37 Decimal('1.0000000000') 6]
action
  0.85
reward
  0.2703302
next state
  [9 79 48074 57869 27 28 32 Decimal('1.0000000000') 0]
```

Comment: I don't know if i am maybe just reading the values wrong, so enlighten me please!

Comment: What environment are you training on? Did you compare the results with other implementations, for example [spinup](https://github.com/openai/spinningup/tree/master/spinup/algos/ddpg) or [baselines](https://github.com/openai/baselines/tree/master/baselines/ddpg)?